# PostgreSQL Select statement very slow due to small JOIN/WHERE filter

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

**2013-05-29: Updated question with latest configuration and extra info. Earlier I was testing in a virtualbox image. Now I am testing on the productive server, which reflects the real world much better. Question should be fully clear now. If you have helped me before, read again carefully**

Currently I have found a query that is very slow in PostgreSQL, though I do not understand how it can be slow. I scaled it down a bit so it's much smaller to post here (and much faster, but still slow!).

Little background: In this project I have adverts that belong to users. Users are part of an area within the country. An area can have multiple child areas, so the area table is a tree. A network is assigned to an area. When filtering on a network it should filter on that area and all its area childs in the tree. Because I can't query against a endless tree I have table that flattens this full tree.

So with 1 query `(SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id = 1)` I get all areas that belong to network 1:
`63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70`

This makes querying very easy.

The slow query (Before testing everything has been VACUUM ANALYZED):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
       INNER JOIN area a7_
               ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND a7_.id IN (SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id IN (1))
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=41.10..34695.53 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=9.327..134.581 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.10..2291276.69 rows=3967 width=12) (actual time=9.326..134.534 rows=60 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (a7_.id = m6_.area_id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22566
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.10..821630.16 rows=317633 width=24) (actual time=0.049..39.638 rows=22666 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan Backward using advert_created_date_idx on advert a0_  (cost=0.00..762000.64 rows=317633 width=16) (actual time=0.013..4.357 rows=2834 loops=1)
                     Filter: (status = 1)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 21
               ->  Materialize  (cost=41.10..73.38 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.004 rows=8 loops=2834)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=41.10..73.30 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.031..0.073 rows=8 loops=1)
                           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=41.10..41.18 rows=8 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.026 rows=8 loops=1)
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on network_area_flatdeep  (cost=4.37..41.06 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.015 rows=8 loops=1)
                                       Recheck Cond: (network_id = 1)
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_c29e880034128b91  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=8 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: (network_id = 1)
                           ->  Index Only Scan using area_pkey on area a7_  (cost=0.00..4.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=8)
                                 Index Cond: (id = network_area_flatdeep.area_id)
                                 Heap Fetches: 8
         ->  Index Scan using member_pkey on member m6_  (cost=0.00..4.61 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=22666)
               Index Cond: (id = a0_.user_id)
               Filter: (status = 1)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Total runtime: 134.698 ms
(23 rows)
```

The subquery itself is:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id IN (1);
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on network_area_flatdeep  (cost=4.37..41.06 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.024 rows=8 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (network_id = 1)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_c29e880034128b91  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=8 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (network_id = 1)
 Total runtime: 0.051 ms
(5 rows)
```

which results in : `63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70`

So I've tried to hard code in the ids. And expected it to be faster (but is not):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
       INNER JOIN area a7_
                   ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND a7_.id IN (63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70)
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=17558.82..17558.97 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=56.594..56.670 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=17558.82..17560.07 rows=498 width=12) (actual time=56.593..56.621 rows=60 loops=1)
         Sort Key: a0_.created_date
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..17541.62 rows=498 width=12) (actual time=0.047..53.808 rows=4478 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3903.99 rows=286 width=4) (actual time=0.027..17.492 rows=8004 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on area a7_  (cost=0.00..144.78 rows=8 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.823 rows=8 loops=1)
                           Filter: (id = ANY ('{63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70}'::integer[]))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 5081
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_70e4fa78bd0f409c on member m6_  (cost=0.00..468.38 rows=152 width=8) (actual time=0.011..1.208 rows=1000 loops=8)
                           Index Cond: (area_id = a7_.id)
                           Filter: (status = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 2
               ->  Index Scan using idx_54f1f40ba76ed395 on advert a0_  (cost=0.00..47.49 rows=19 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=8004)
                     Index Cond: (user_id = m6_.id)
                     Filter: (status = 1)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 56.744 ms
(18 rows)

Time: 57.995 ms
```

I tried to put the subquery in the INNER JOIN:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
       INNER JOIN area a7_
               ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id 
               AND m6_.area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id IN     (1))
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4.37..34966.73 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=2.957..42.443 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.37..2311599.10 rows=3967 width=12) (actual time=2.956..42.394 rows=60 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=4.37..2302173.51 rows=3967 width=20) (actual time=2.949..42.099 rows=60 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (m6_.area_id = network_area_flatdeep.area_id)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22333
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2230853.09 rows=316797 width=16) (actual time=0.028..18.612 rows=2829 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan Backward using advert_created_date_idx on advert a0_  (cost=0.00..762000.64 rows=317633 width=16) (actual time=0.012..3.802 rows=2834 loops=1)
                           Filter: (status = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 21
                     ->  Index Scan using member_pkey on member m6_  (cost=0.00..4.61 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2834)
                           Index Cond: (id = a0_.user_id)
                           Filter: (status = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 0
               ->  Materialize  (cost=4.37..41.14 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.004 rows=8 loops=2829)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on network_area_flatdeep  (cost=4.37..41.06 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.015 rows=8 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (network_id = 1)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_c29e880034128b91  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=8 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (network_id = 1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using area_pkey on area a7_  (cost=0.00..2.37 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=60)
               Index Cond: (id = m6_.area_id)
               Heap Fetches: 60
 Total runtime: 42.538 ms
(22 rows)
```

I tried to get rid of the subquery and make a proper JOIN statement to `network_area_flatdeep` (I STRONGLY PREFER THIS VERSION):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
       INNER JOIN area a7_
               ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id 
       INNER JOIN network_area_flatdeep n14_
               ON a7_.id = n14_.area_id
                  AND ( n14_.network_id IN ( 1 ) )
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
                                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=30031.18..30031.33 rows=60 width=12) (actual time=62.968..63.045 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=30031.18..30033.51 rows=934 width=12) (actual time=62.967..62.991 rows=60 loops=1)
         Sort Key: a0_.created_date
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..29998.92 rows=934 width=12) (actual time=0.157..60.280 rows=4478 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..4401.66 rows=536 width=4) (actual time=0.029..20.488 rows=8004 loops=1)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..120.69 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.084 rows=8 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using idx_c29e880034128b91 on network_area_flatdeep n14_  (cost=0.00..60.47 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.019 rows=8 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (network_id = 1)
                           ->  Index Only Scan using area_pkey on area a7_  (cost=0.00..4.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=8)
                                 Index Cond: (id = n14_.area_id)
                                 Heap Fetches: 8
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_70e4fa78bd0f409c on member m6_  (cost=0.00..283.88 rows=152 width=8) (actual time=0.011..1.278 rows=1000 loops=8)
                           Index Cond: (area_id = a7_.id)
                           Filter: (status = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 2
               ->  Index Scan using idx_54f1f40ba76ed395 on advert a0_  (cost=0.00..47.57 rows=19 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=8004)
                     Index Cond: (user_id = m6_.id)
                     Filter: (status = 1)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 63.125 ms
(21 rows)
```

Changing `IN` to `=` doesn't helper either.

I tried using EXISTS as suggested by wilderplasser with an answer below.

When I either remove the ORDER BY or the network criteria, the query is fast (2ms). But why can't they play nice together?

Now then... when I change the network_id from '1' to '10'. The query is extremely fast like I want. 10 is a root network that contains ALL areas. So apperently the LESS results the JOIN needs to filter out, the faster the query is.

The structure looks like this:

```
area (mapped to network 10 which contains 5089 areas in flat table and is FAST)
|    |---- area 1 (network 1 which contains 8 areas in flat table and is SLOW)
|        |--- more areas
|-- ALOT MORE areas
|-- etc
```

Changing network 1 to 10 gives: 3.265 ms

To summarize the difference:

network 1 has 8 areas in `network_area_flatdeep`
network 10 has 5089 areas in `network_area_flatdeep`

So INNER JOIN using network 1 is very slow, INNER JOIN using network 10 is very fast. Same behavior with subqueries.

Advert table

```
353804 rows
                                                                   Table "public.advert"
           Column            |              Type              |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                          | integer                        | not null default nextval('advert_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 user_id                     | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 advert_category_id          | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 currency_id                 | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 advert_kind_id              | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 advert_price_id             | integer                        |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 external_source_id          | integer                        |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 status                      | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 type                        | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 title                       | character varying(60)          | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 description                 | text                           | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 price                       | numeric(19,2)                  | default NULL::numeric                               | main     |              | 
 accepting_bids              | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 promoted                    | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 edited_date                 | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone           | plain    |              | 
 created_date                | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 archived_date               | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone           | plain    |              | 
 views                       | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 checked_date                | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone           | plain    |              | 
 archived_by_cron            | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 unarchived_by_cron          | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 containting_forbidden_words | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 external_id                 | character varying(255)         | default NULL::character varying                     | extended |              | 
 new_product                 | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "advert_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "advert_external_idx_uq" UNIQUE, btree (external_id, external_source_id)
    "advert_archived_date_idx" btree (archived_date)
    "advert_checked_date_idx" btree (checked_date)
    "advert_created_date_idx" btree (created_date)
    "advert_edited_date_idx" btree (edited_date)
    "advert_external_id_idx" btree (external_id)
    "advert_price_idx" btree (price)
    "advert_status_idx" btree (status)
    "advert_type_idx" btree (type)
    "advert_views_idx" btree (views)
    "idx_54f1f40b38248176" btree (currency_id)
    "idx_54f1f40b54b67d66" btree (advert_price_id)
    "idx_54f1f40b9a2e6cff" btree (advert_kind_id)
    "idx_54f1f40ba76ed395" btree (user_id)
    "idx_54f1f40bb167b375" btree (external_source_id)
    "idx_54f1f40bd4436821" btree (advert_category_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_54f1f40b38248176" FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES currency(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_54f1f40b54b67d66" FOREIGN KEY (advert_price_id) REFERENCES advertprice(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_54f1f40b9a2e6cff" FOREIGN KEY (advert_kind_id) REFERENCES advertkind(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_54f1f40ba76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "fk_54f1f40bb167b375" FOREIGN KEY (external_source_id) REFERENCES externalsource(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_54f1f40bd4436821" FOREIGN KEY (advert_category_id) REFERENCES advertcategory(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
Referenced by:
    TABLE "advert_photo" CONSTRAINT "fk_1c939974d07eccb6" FOREIGN KEY (advert_id) REFERENCES advert(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "banner" CONSTRAINT "fk_6f9db8e7d07eccb6" FOREIGN KEY (advert_id) REFERENCES advert(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    TABLE "advertbid" CONSTRAINT "fk_fccdba75d07eccb6" FOREIGN KEY (advert_id) REFERENCES advert(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

Area table:

```
5089 rows
                                               Table "public.area"
   Column   |  Type   |                     Modifiers                     | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer | not null default nextval('area_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 network_id | integer |                                                   | plain   |              | 
 parent_id  | integer |                                                   | plain   |              | 
 selectable | boolean | not null                                          | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "area_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_d7943d6834128b91" btree (network_id)
    "idx_d7943d68727aca70" btree (parent_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_d7943d6834128b91" FOREIGN KEY (network_id) REFERENCES network(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_d7943d68727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "network_area_flat" CONSTRAINT "fk_10aae5b2bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "area_language" CONSTRAINT "fk_17d42f7dbd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "area_zip_code" CONSTRAINT "fk_62a3bf90bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "member" CONSTRAINT "fk_70e4fa78bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    TABLE "network_area_flatdeep" CONSTRAINT "fk_c29e8800bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "area" CONSTRAINT "fk_d7943d68727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

Member table:

```
182450 rows
                                                               Table "public.member"
        Column         |              Type              |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                        | not null default nextval('member_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 language_id           | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 area_id               | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 company_id            | integer                        |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 external_source_id    | integer                        |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 email                 | character varying(255)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 password              | character varying(40)          | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 status                | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 name                  | character varying(150)         | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 zip_code              | character varying(20)          |                                                     | extended |              | 
 phone_number          | character varying(120)         | default NULL::character varying                     | extended |              | 
 using_email_service   | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 edited_date           | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone           | plain    |              | 
 created_date          | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 hiding_on_own_network | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 staff                 | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 superuser             | boolean                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 external_id           | character varying(255)         | default NULL::character varying                     | extended |              | 
 last_login_date       | timestamp(0) without time zone | default NULL::timestamp without time zone           | plain    |              | 
 deleted_adverts       | integer                        | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "member_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "user_email_idx_uq" UNIQUE, btree (email)
    "user_external_idx_uq" UNIQUE, btree (external_id, external_source_id)
    "idx_70e4fa7882f1baf4" btree (language_id)
    "idx_70e4fa78979b1ad6" btree (company_id)
    "idx_70e4fa78b167b375" btree (external_source_id)
    "idx_70e4fa78bd0f409c" btree (area_id)
    "user_external_id_idx" btree (external_id)
    "user_name_idx" btree (name)
    "user_status_idx" btree (status)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_70e4fa7882f1baf4" FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES language(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_70e4fa78979b1ad6" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "fk_70e4fa78b167b375" FOREIGN KEY (external_source_id) REFERENCES externalsource(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "fk_70e4fa78bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_link" CONSTRAINT "fk_4c2dd538a76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "advert" CONSTRAINT "fk_54f1f40ba76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "banner" CONSTRAINT "fk_6f9db8e7a76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    TABLE "user_admin_module_permission" CONSTRAINT "fk_74fee7cea76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "user_admin_resource_permission" CONSTRAINT "fk_c9fcf279a76ed395" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES member(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

Network_area_flatdeep table:

```
10177 rows
                                                           Table "public.network_area_flatdeep"
    Column    |              Type              |                             Modifiers                              | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer                        | not null default nextval('network_area_flatdeep_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 network_id   | integer                        | not null                                                           | plain   |              | 
 area_id      | integer                        | not null                                                           | plain   |              | 
 created_date | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null                                                           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "network_area_flatdeep_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "area_flatdeep_idx_uq" UNIQUE, btree (area_id, network_id, created_date)
    "idx_c29e880034128b91" btree (network_id)
    "idx_c29e8800bd0f409c" btree (area_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_c29e880034128b91" FOREIGN KEY (network_id) REFERENCES network(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "fk_c29e8800bd0f409c" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

Short server config:

```
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3), 64-bit

            name            |  current_setting   |        source        
----------------------------+--------------------+----------------------
 shared_buffers             | 1800MB             | configuration file
 work_mem                   | 4MB                | configuration file
```

Conclusion:

The more data (less filtered out), the faster the query is. I'm a bit clueless now. How can PostgreSQL be so slow on this? Again: 40ms doesn't look extremely slow, but with the real query with a big SELECT statement, queries are 1.5s most of the time and can take up to 3s.

All filtering is done on indexes. The ordering is done on an index too.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve this simple filter I clearly need to separate data?

Comment: 1) VACUUM ANALYZE 2) EXPLAIN ANALYZE (instead of EXPLAIN) 3) table definitions (including indexes) 4) configuration (**at least** {work_mem, effective_cache_size, random_page_cost})

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: 1) I did vacuum analyze. No difference.  2) Added to post  3) Added to post  4) All commented out in configuration. Guess it's using default values?

Comment: Before 9.1, the default values in the configuration were way off. Try setting effective_cache_size to total_memory_in_the_machine minus (a few hundred M), set work_mem to a few * 10M (and maybe later, set random_page_cost to 1.5) BTW: you have many indices. The indices on the boolean fields (or other low-cardinality fields) are close to useless.

Comment: Just a side note: 8.4 is already pretty old. 9.x has several performance improvements as well. Migrating to 9.2 shouldn't be a big deal. You should really consider that (although I doubt it will solve this specific problem)

Comment: Config summary? http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Server_Configuration

Comment: Upgraded to 9.2. Same problem. Also updated OP with config summary.

Comment: It might be the fact that I run within a boxed environment (vagrant). I'm going to continue hunt this issue when I have it running on the upcoming production server as I understand from articles that DB's are depended on server config a lot. I don't want to waste my and you guys time with this configuration. Thanks so far! Might continue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of plan do you get when you remove the apparently needless (and thus distracting) join on area?

```
SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id IN (1))
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
```

Comment: It's faster but not fast enough. I ended up with this variation:
`AND (a7_.id IN (SELECT a18_.id FROM network_area_flatdeep n19_ INNER JOIN area a18_ ON n19_.area_id = a18_.id WHERE n19_.network_id IN (?) AND n19_.area_id = a7_.id))`

Why? Just trial and error. I tried all combinations. Somehow this makes my production query (bigger) from 2s to less than 0.1s :/ Even when I change it to EXISTS it's 2s again!

In some situations it's slower with other criteria. In that case I use the JOIN version. So my App has a IF statement to build query for optimal performance. Not ideal :( but it works

Comment: I will tweak more before I accept any answer. Thanks for your suggestion here too. The changes you suggested on my other question @  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815561/slow-or-statement-in-postgresql helped me alot too on this query (filter on PK of relation).

Comment: Did some tweaking within my app to decide whether to use JOINS or a Subquery. Which both perform in some situations better. Though my (nasty) modification performs better than you suggested query. It pointed me into the right direction. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the `IN(subquery)` by the corresponding `EXISTS(correlated subquery)`

```
SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
INNER JOIN area a7_
               ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id 
WHERE a0_.status IN ( 1 )
AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
AND EXISTS (
     SELECT*
     FROM network_area_flatdeep xx
     WHERE xx.area_id = m6_.area_id
     AND xx.network_id IN  (2)
     )
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60
   ;
```

An you do need of course primary keys and relavant foreign keys. I don'rt know about `network_area_flatdeep.area_id` , if it is not a PK or FK, you might need an index on it (or make it part of a composite PK)

UPDATE: a testbed with synthetic data:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE Table area
 ( id   SERIAL  not null PRIMARY KEY
 , zzzz varchar
        );

CREATE Table member
 ( id   SERIAL  not null PRIMARY KEY
 , language_id  integer not null DEFAULT 0
 , area_id      integer not null REFERENCES area(id)
 , company_id   integer
 , external_source_id   integer
 , status       integer not null  DEFAULT 0
 , name varchar not null
 , zip_code     varchar not null
 , phone_number varchar default NULL
 , using_email_service  boolean not null DEFAULT False
 , edited_date  timestamp(0) without time zone  default NULL
 , created_date timestamp(0) without time zone  not null
 , hiding_on_own_network        boolean not null DEFAULT False
 , staff        boolean not null DEFAULT False
 , superuser    boolean not null DEFAULT False
 , external_id  varchar default NULL
        );

CREATE TABLE advert
 ( id   SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 , user_id      integer NOT NULL  REFERENCES member(id)
 , advert_category_id   integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , currency_id  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , advert_kind_id       integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , advert_price_id      integer
 , external_source_id   integer
 , status       integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , title        varchar NOT NULL
 , description  text NOT NULL
 , price        numeric(10,2) default NULL
 , accepting_bids       boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT False
 , promoted     boolean NOT NULL  DEFAULT False
 , edited_date  timestamp(0) without time zone default NULL
 , created_date timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL
 , archived_date        timestamp(0) without time zone  default NULL
 , views        integer NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0
 , checked_date timestamp(0) without time zone default NULL
 , archived_by_cron     boolean NOT NULL  DEFAULT False
 , unarchived_by_cron   boolean NOT NULL  DEFAULT False
 , containting_forbidden_words  boolean NOT NULL  DEFAULT False
 , external_id  varchar default NULL
        );

CREATE INDEX advert_created_date_idx ON advert (created_date);

CREATE Table network_area_flatdeep
        -- the surrogate key in a junction table is questionable
 ( id   SERIAL not null PRIMARY KEY
 , network_id   integer not null -- REFERENCES network(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 , area_id      integer not null REFERENCES area(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 , created_date timestamp(0) without time zone not null
        -- the date in the below constraint is questionable
 , CONSTRAINT area_flatdeep_idx_uq UNIQUE (area_id, network_id, created_date)
        );
CREATE INDEX idx_c29e880034128b91 ON network_area_flatdeep(network_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_c29e8800bd0f409c ON network_area_flatdeep(area_id);
INSERT INTO area ( zzzz)
SELECT 'Zzzz_' || gs::text
FROM generate_series(1,39) gs
        ;

INSERT INTO network_area_flatdeep
        -- the surrogate key in a junction table is questionable
 ( network_id , area_id , created_date)
SELECT gs % 7 , aa.id, now()
FROM generate_series(1,76) gs
JOIN area aa ON aa.id = 1+gs % 39
        ;


INSERT INTO member
 ( area_id , name , zip_code, created_date)
SELECT aa.id
        , 'Member_'|| gs::text
        , 'Code_'|| gs::text
        , now()
FROM generate_series(1, 10086) gs
JOIN area aa ON aa.id = 1 + gs % 39
        ;
INSERT INTO advert( user_id , title, description, edited_date , created_date)
SELECT 1+ (gs* 321) % 10086
        , 'Tit_'|| gs::text
        , 'Desc_'|| gs::text
        , now()
        , now() - (random() * 10000 * '1 sec'::interval)
 from generate_series(1,47569 ) gs
        ;

UPDATE member SET status = 1 WHERE random() < .3;
UPDATE advert SET status = 1 WHERE random() < .3;

VACUUM ANALYZE member;
VACUUM ANALYZE advert;
VACUUM ANALYZE area;
VACUUM ANALYZE network_area_flatdeep;
```

My query executes in 12ms (PG-9.1), with the same plan as the OPs.
(so this must be a configuration issue)

Comment: Same performance: 305.512 ms. I would expect this query too be much heavier by design, as this subquery is ran for every row. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. (it is a legend that is only believed by people who were exposed to mysql) Just check the plan. On the contrary: it is the `IN()` that *could* cause problems (in short: because it needs to remove duplicates and NULLs)

Comment: Ok interesting :) How I see that it's removing duplicates? To answer your last question: All are FKs + I don't have composite keys because that makes ORM operations much more complex in Doctrine2 (and not recommended). I might gona rework my query so I pass in the values for IN through PHP. So make a extra PHP step. Though I don't consider this as a real solution.

Comment: In your case it removes the dupicates from the `IN(nework_area_flatdeep sub query)` by means of the hash -> hash join. (given that it is only 76 rows it is not that costly. But it *could get* costly if there were more (or larger, or sparser) rows)

Comment: Mine executes in 12ms here (on a stripped down data model)

Comment: Works very fast here too. I upgraded to 9.2 too. But on my own data model the issue still exists :( Will be doing some more tests and remove indexes on boolean fields.

Comment: See last post in OP. I wait until I can test this ib the real server it will be running on. Don't want to waste my/your time too much on this configuration. Thanks so far. Might need continue this issue later.

Answer (score 0):

A small variation on one of your queries

```
SELECT a0_.id  AS id0
FROM   advert a0_
       INNER JOIN member m6_
               ON a0_.user_id = m6_.id
       INNER JOIN area a7_
               ON m6_.area_id = a7_.id 
       INNER JOIN (
                SELECT area_id
                FROM network_area_flatdeep
                WHERE network_id IN (2)
                ) network_area_flatdeep n14_
               ON a7_.id = n14_.area_id
WHERE  a0_.status IN ( 1 )
       AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
```

Comment: Nope, same performance :( I updated the question too. It should be much more clear now and I can test on a production server now instead of local virtual box. Btw you made a typo. Remove `retwork_area_flatdeep` before the n14_

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you turn the query around? So first you select the areas and then you join in the members and adverts on that one. You can also limit the join by adding the WHERE part on the `JOIN` directly.

```
SELECT a0_.id  AS id0

FROM    area a7_
        LEFT JOIN member m6_
            ON a7_.id = m6_.area_id AND m6_.status IN ( 1 )
        LEFT JOIN advert a0_
            ON m6_.id = a0_.user_id

WHERE   a7_.id IN (SELECT area_id FROM network_area_flatdeep WHERE network_id IN (1))
        AND a0_.status IN ( 1 )

ORDER  BY a0_.created_date DESC
LIMIT  60;
```